# How do I prevent fonts sizes and line weights from scaling in exported graphics?

Tags: graphics, export, fonts, pdf-format

It's common to export graphics from *Mathematica* that are subsequently scaled to various sizes that cannot (at least not conveniently) be anticipated. This is problematic in cases where (as is common) fonts and line weights need to fixed (e.g. throughout a document or presentation, or simply to prevent a figure from looking ridiculous).

For example, if the default options for fonts and line weights are satisfactory, then

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[5 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

will produce a figure with correct font sizes an line weights

[image]

and scaling this figure within *Mathematica* (e.g. by dragging the resize frame) will preserve these font sizes and line weights:

[image]

However, if I export the original graphic in a resizable format (i.e., choosing "Save Graphic As..." and specifying a PDF "Vector Representation", which, as far as I can tell, is the only form suitable for subsequent resizing), the fonts and line weights scale with the graphic

[image]

which is not the desired result.

Is there a way to generate and export graphics so that font sizes and line weights are preserved when the exported graphic is resized?

Comment: You might take a look at the `ImageSize` option (e.g. for `Show[]` and `ImageResolution` for export, though I only used the latter one for `PNG` images, it might also work for the font size and line with in `eps` exports.

Comment: I think the point of PDF as an export format is that it doesn't change any aspect of the original graphics, whether line art or text size and positioning. However, if you open a PDF graphic up in something like Adobe Illustrator, you'll be able to resize text independently of graphics (because the font sizing commands affect only the text).

Comment: @cormullion: That depend on what "change" means. In the context of my scenario, the behavior I'm trying to overcome is that resizing *does* change font size and line weight. I'd have thought that PDF had a way to say "make this x points wherever it appears", but it might not, which would surprise me.

Comment: I think, the reason for the "change" you're expierincing is, that the scaling (via drag) you are performing, does change the (absolute) size of the pdf, but neither the size in cm with respect to the resolution. Hence your - say doubled in size -- image does take the double space in the PDF, while inside getting rendered with respect to old size/resolution. Hence the bigger line width and font size.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in `PDF` except maybe using Javascript in Adobe Reader (which won't work in other readers). With `SVG` it could also be done using Javascript if you plan to display the graphic in a browser (e.g., by catching the `onresize` event). Of course that goes into off-topic territory for this site.

Answer (score 5):

The main point is, that you can change two things, the resolution of the image (which is for example the option `ImageResolution` in `dpi` but only for `PNG` and not for `EPS`) and the actual size of the image using `ImageSize`. That one is a little tricky, because it is given in `dpi` with respect to `72 dpi`.

The following changes your image

```
A = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[5 x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

to an image of size 24 cm (and hence the standard font size of 10pt gets quite small and so does the line width with respect to the complete image)

```
B = Show[A, ImageSize -> 24/2.54*72]
```

where the calculations are due to conversion into `in` and the typical Resolution of `72 dpi`. To export something like that you can use

```
Export["~/Desktop/A.eps", B]
```

or for PNG you can further specify the dpi the image should then have using

```
Export["~/Desktop/A.png", B, ImageResolution -> 150]
```

to get 150 dpi. That does than look lie the following

[image: 150 dpi 24 cm image]

That way you have a nice way to control the font size of your graphic and the actual size of the result (for later usage e.g. in LaTeX).

**edit:** Oh. I overlooked your PDF point and red eps. But it works for PDF, too.