# How can I scale a plot in vector graphic or PDF form?

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

I am not at all a computer graphics expert, but it seems that portable document format (PDF) files have a "native size," even though they may (and usually do!) contain vector graphics that can be scaled essentially infinitely without loss of quality.

In Mathematica, the `ImageSize` option in graphics and plotting commands like `Graphics`, `Plot`, and `ListPlot` allows one to specify the size of images such as graphics and plots.  One way to use the `ImageSize` option is to simply specify a width $w$.  The image will be given that width and the image's height will be automatically chosen so as to maintain the image's `AspectRatio` (which, for plots, has the default `1/GoldenRatio`).

Now, in the [documentation for `ImageSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageSize.html) (see the Details section), it is stated that one possible specification for width $w$ (and for height $h$) is $72 di$, which specifies $di$ inches (before magnification), according to the Documentation.  This means that if I want an image (for example, a `ListPlot`) to be $di$ inches in width, I just need to use the option `ImageSize -> (72*di)` within the `ListPlot`.  (I'm not certain, but it may be necessary to round the result to an integer, since I'm not sure if `ImageSize` accepts fractional/decimal arguments.  If so, then I can just use `ImageSize -> Round[72*di]`).

So here's an example.  Suppose that I'm told by a publisher that my image should be 8 inches wide.  So I use `ImageSize -> (72*8)` in `ListPlot`.  Then I customize my `ListPlot` in a variety of ways: I use the `BaseStyle` option to set the font size and family and I use `Disk[]` shapes as the `PlotMarkers`.  I play with the parameters until my plot looks nice.  For example:

```
xdata = Range[0, 0.05, 0.00115];
ydata = Sin[160*xdata];

pmSize = 10;(* size of PlotMarkers *)
pm = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> pmSize];(* PlotMarkers *)

imgSizeInInches = 8;
imgSizeInPixels = Round[72*imgSizeInInches];(* ImageSize *)

pl = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}],
  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x (unit)", "y (unit)"},
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[Medium],
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[Medium],
  BaseStyle -> {26, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
  PlotMarkers -> pm,
  ImageSize -> imgSizeInPixels]
```

which gives this output:

[image: FirstOutput]

Now I export to a PDF file called "example.pdf":

```
Export["example.pdf", pl, "AllowRasterization" -> False]
```

I open this PDF in Adobe Acrobat.  Adobe Acrobat tells me (see the status bar at the bottom left) that, as promised, the image is 8 inches wide:

[image: PDFImage]

Yea!  I am pleased, and so is my publisher: the PDF file's native size is 8 inches wide!

***Now, however,*** suppose that the publisher changes its mind and now wants the PDF image to be natively 5 inches wide instead.  My first thought is to simply set `ImageSize` to `72*5`.  That will make the width of the image 5 inches.  I do this by simply setting `imgSizeInInches = 5;` in my code:

```
xdata = Range[0, 0.05, 0.00115];
ydata = Sin[160*xdata];

pmSize = 10;(* size of PlotMarkers *)
pm = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> pmSize];(* PlotMarkers *)

imgSizeInInches = 5;
imgSizeInPixels = Round[72*imgSizeInInches];(* ImageSize *)

pl = ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}],
  PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {"x (unit)", "y (unit)"},
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[Medium],
  AxesStyle -> Thickness[Medium],
  BaseStyle -> {26, FontFamily -> "Arial"},
  PlotMarkers -> pm,
  ImageSize -> imgSizeInPixels]
```

...which gives this output:

[image: SecondOutput]

When I export to a PDF file using `Export["example.pdf", pl, "AllowRasterization" -> False]` and open the resulting file in Adobe Acrobat, Adobe Acrobat confirms that the native width of the image is 5 inches:

[image: NewOut]

**But** now the image is crammed -- the size of the image decreased, but the sizes of the font and the plot markers did not.

***So, my question is:*** is there any way to simply **scale** the image so that the PDF file's "native" size decreases while *also* proportionally decreasing the size of the text, plot markers, etc?  In that way, the *entire* image would "shrink" proportionally -- although without loss of quality since the image is a vector graphic!

Please not that I do not want to rasterize the image; I would like to keep the image as a vector graphic.  Thank you for any help you can give with this confusing issue.

Comment: If the font size was ok in the first plot and then you made the second plot 5/8 the width why not try that on the font size.

Comment: You might want to look at these two related questions: [Q1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16009/3066), 
[Q2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8409/3066)

Comment: Also check out the documentation for [Magnify](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Magnify.html).

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442/131

Comment: Related: [(2475)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2475/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### `Magnification` and `Magnify`

You can use the `Magnification` option for magnifying the whole graphics:

```
Style[pl, Magnification -> 5/8]
Export["example2.pdf", Style[pl, Magnification -> 5/8]]
```

You could also try `Magnify`:

```
Export["example3.pdf", Magnify[pl, 5/8]]
```

Note that `Magnify` is affected by the global `Magnification` option which you can access by `Options[$FrontEnd, Magnification]`. To get consistent result when you have non-default value of this option you could set it locally:

```
Export["example3.pdf", Style[Magnify[pl, 5/8], Magnification -> 1]]
```

Both ways are not perfect: you can notice slight "floating" of the frame labels. In this case `Magnify` gives almost identical result to `Magnification` (you can notice difference in thickness of the `Frame`) but there were cases when `Magnify` worked incorrectly. So you should try both ways.

I have tried also to use `Inset` for scaling but unfortunately it works identical to `ImageSize`.

---

### `Scaled` functionality

Another possibility is to use `Scaled` font size and scaled sizes for plot markers from the start (note that I renamed your `imgSizeInPixels` variable to `imgSizeInPoints` because it is [PostScript points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29), not pixels):

```
xdata = Range[0, 0.05, 0.00115];
ydata = Sin[160*xdata];

pmSize = .04;(*scaled size of PlotMarkers*)
pm = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}];(*PlotMarkers*)
imgSizeInInches = 8;
imgSizeInPoints = Round[72*imgSizeInInches];(*ImageSize*)

pl = 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x (unit)", "y (unit)"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[Medium], AxesStyle -> Thickness[Medium], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[1/30], FontFamily -> "Arial"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {pm, pmSize}, ImageSize -> imgSizeInPoints, 
  ImagePadding -> {{45, 20}, {40, 1}}]
```

Note that I have to set explicit `ImagePadding` because behavior of default `ImagePadding -> All` is incorrect in this case (clearly it is a bug). Now you can set any `ImageSize` you like while preserving the original appearance of the plot with exceptions for "floating" frame labels (seems to be another bug), non-scalable tick marks and the need to specify explicit `ImagePadding` for every `ImageSize` (AFAIK it is not possible to specify scaled `ImagePadding`).

---

### Your own scaling functionality implementation

Given that `Scaled` functionality for `FontSize` is very buggy and `ImagePadding` is gedanken, I suggest to implement needed scaling functionality by yourself directly based on your `imgSizeInInches` variable.

Here is an example:

```
xdata = Range[0, 0.05, 0.00115];
ydata = Sin[160*xdata];

imgSizeInInches = 5;
pmSize = 1.25*imgSizeInInches;(*size of PlotMarkers*)
pm = Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> pmSize];(*PlotMarkers*)
imgSizeInPoints = Round[72*imgSizeInInches];(*ImageSize*)

pl = 
 ListPlot[Transpose[{xdata, ydata}], PlotRange -> {-1.1, 1.1}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x (unit)", "y (unit)"}, 
  FrameStyle -> Thickness[.001], AxesStyle -> Thickness[.001], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 3.25*imgSizeInInches, 
    FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotMarkers -> pm, 
  ImageSize -> imgSizeInPoints, 
  ImagePadding -> (imgSizeInInches*{{12, 2.5}, {9, .1}})]
```

Changing `imgSizeInInches` scales the plot almost correctly but frame labels still float relatively to frame tick labels and tick marks still have fixed lengths and do not scale with the plot. The workaround for the latter is to use the `CustomTicks` package for automatic generation of scalable `Ticks` specification. One possible workaround for frame labels may be to use `Framed` instead of `FrameLabel` (have not tried it myself).

Comment: Thanks so much! I experienced a strange issue when trying your suggestions of `Magnification` and `Magnify` above. When I enter `Export["example2.pdf", Style[pl, Magnification -> 5/8]]`, Adobe Acrobat says that the resulting **example2.pdf** has a width of 5 inches -- as expected and intended! ***But,*** when I enter `Export["example3.pdf", Magnify[pl, 5/8]]`, Adobe Acrobat says that the resulting **example3.pdf** has a width of **3.60 inches**, which is unexpected and unintended. I tried restarting the kernel. Can anyone please try this and see if you can reproduce this issue?

Comment: @Andrew It depends on the global `Magnification` setting. If you evaluate `SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 1]`, then `Export["example3.pdf", Magnify[pl, 5/8]]` gives expected result with width of 5 inches. You can mimic this behavior by `Export["example3.pdf", Style[Magnify[pl, 5/8], Magnification -> 1]]`.

Comment: Why is this post community wiki?  Was this a case of automatic conversion, and I would you like me to remove it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was auto-converted to CW, please convert it into a normal post if possible.

Comment: Done! $\phantom{}$

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know if there are any other answers of yours that were auto-converted like that.  Stack Exchange has since disabled that feature, and we never really needed it here that I could tell as people were not in the habit of incessantly "bumping" their posts with edits.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for the explanation. I wonder about this feature since it happened with this post but never bothered myself to ask a question on Meta. If the memory serves, this happened with me only once.

Comment: Since this is an answer from 2013 I wonder, would you still recommend this approach, or has some new technology superseded this?